# Javascript fetch not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have implemented javascript fetch to call webapi in MVC view cshtml page. It is working in Chrome/Edge, but not working in IE. How to make fetch() work in IE.

Below code used in my application for calling MVC action method using fetch()

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/3.5.0/bluebird.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.3/fetch.js"></script>

    $("#btnExcelDownload").click(function(){
        window.fetch("/Home/DownloadExcelTemplate", {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers({
                'AntiForgeryToken': 'XSS6GDB'
            })
       })
    .then(response => response.blob())
     .then(blob => {

        var linkElement = document.createElement('a');
        var url =  URL.createObjectURL(blob);

         linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
         linkElement.setAttribute("download", '@request.Name'+"_Catalog.xlsx");
         //for Firefox
         document.body.appendChild(linkElement);

         linkElement.click();
         document.body.removeChild(linkElement);   });

    });
```

Comment: I'm still facing issue even after adding polyfill as above